# Yii2 кэширует вывод страниц

Tags: php, yii2, yii, кэширование

Здравствуйте. Проблема: редактирую вьюхи по ftp, обновляю страницу, а изменений нет. Чищу кэш в браузере, обновляю, а изменений нет. Захожу на страниуц с др. браузера и тут нет изменений. Захожу с др. устройства, а изменений все нет :(
Изменения появляются только, если раз пятьдесят обновить страницу или подождать часок другой потом снова открыть.
В чем может быть дело?

Это обострилось когда перенес сайт с домашней машины на удаленный сервер. На домашнем сервере такое бывало редко редко. Эта проблема особенно обостряется по вечерам, когда у меня интернет работает не стабильно (перебои). Может это не yii2 может, а скажем роутер кэширует или т.п.?

Comment: почистите папку web/assets. и в assets файлах оставьте только $baseUrl

Comment: web/assets само собой чистил не помогло. Там же то только стили да скрипты. А у меня вся страница кэшируется. Насчет $baseUrl не понял. В имеете ввиду удалить $basePath и оставить только $baseUrl или что?

Comment: Все верно поняли. Если не поможет, то почитайте про forceCopy